# create a charge with Stripe and Delphi

Tags: api, delphi, stripe-payments

I am trying to create a charge in Stripe following API documentation but without success :

```
  jsnObj := TJSONObject.Create;
  jsnObj.AddPair('amount', TJSONNumber.Create('111')); 
  jsnObj.AddPair('currency', 'eur');
  jsnObj.AddPair('customer', 'cus_JL30ptApR3U2gL');
  jsnObj.AddPair('description', 'My First Test');
  ss := TStringStream.Create(jsnObj.ToString); 
  rs := TStringStream.Create;
  IdHTTP1.Request.BasicAuthentication := True;
  IdHTTP1.Request.Username := ApiKey ;   //  test private key
  IdHTTP1.Post('https://api.stripe.com/v1/charges', ss, rs);
  StatusBar1.SimpleText := IdHTTP1.ResponseText;
```

the result is always error :

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "parameter_missing",
    "doc_url": "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/parameter-missing",
    "message": "Must provide source or customer.",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
```

}

Http returns 400 bad request.

All data is correct but the source parameter is missing as Stripe documentation states that it is optional so I include customer parameter instead and it should work.
Other calls to the Stripe API are successful with the same code (connect, retrieve objects etc.)

Thanks for any tips..

Comment: I don't think source is really optional and reading the docs needs to be provided.

Comment: Have you checked the same request with Postman?

Comment: This has been solved in [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67420010/json-sent-with-indy-is-not-received-as-it-is-sent-by-stripe-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67420010/json-sent-with-indy-is-not-received-as-it-is-sent-by-stripe-api)